# adb install with install "apk from unknown source" is off?

Tags: android

Will I be able to execute abd install or in any other way be able to install an apk without turning on the "unknown source" option in settings ?

Comment: This is a good thing to try by yourself and learn.

Comment: Technically its not possible because of the security limitations. However you can check if the unknown sources is enabled in the settings and prompt user to enable it. Note that it will not work before installing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you will not be able to, this is intentional for security